# Fire filter event on select in Kendo UI combobox

Tags: combobox, kendo-ui, dojo, telerik, kendo-combobox

I've got a lot of kendo comboboxes in angular project. The desired behaviour I want to get: when I select combobox item, filter event is fired, as if I've wrote the name of item.
Is there any easy ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

When the value of the combobox is changed by the user the change event is fired, you could do there whatever you want.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#events-change

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! I've used `select` event instead of `change`. I've append filter to combobox with my own hand, but i've got some troubles with that. For example, after filter is appended and i open combobox it's clears itself! Also i've got a lot of comboboxes, so they have different text value fileld. So it's very inconvinient for me. I thought may be i can call filter programmatically, as if i press on a keyboard?

Comment: I don't get exactly what you want? You want to filter combobox2 when some value is selected in combobox1? Can you show some code?

Comment: I didn't mean cascade filtering. I meant, that i have a big project. I want, after i select item in combobox, call filter. Here's an [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/UbUZi).
I can compose filter on my own, but i don't want to do it. I want to call something, as if i press a keyboard button (like when you write item name, you want to find).

Comment: Filter is not an event, is a configuration property. May be you need something like this? [change value](https://jsfiddle.net/56omxkv1/4/)